# Makefile Issues: Error 127, 255, running programs within makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am a student in ECE working on a programming assignment; it has already been submitted and is being graded, but I still want to know why my makefile isn't working. When I run the file on our school server with the command 'make tests' it responds

'make: testq: command not found.
make *** tests error 127

If I run 'make testq12345' it will actually run my program "myar" and produce the output file, but it will then give an error 255. I don't understand the issue, or why the makefile cannot find the targets. I've searched via stackoverflow and other sources about these errors but don't understand and can't find a workable solution. If it matters I'm running it on a Linux server.

I am running it in CS311/Homework4/test which contains the makefile, programs and text files.

Thanks for your time and assistance; its appreciated.

```
#
#  $RCSfile$
#  $Revision$
#  $Author$
#  $Date$
#  $Log$
#
# Author: Cody R Crawford
# Email: crawfoco@onid.orst.edu
# Course: CS311-400
# Homework: 4
# Citations:
#   http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/
#       For examples, guidance, and genera understanding
# Assumptions: I assume you want the .o files to show up unless 
# you specifically command 'clean'
#########################################################

CC=gcc
DEBUG=-g
CFLAGS=$(DEBUG) -Wall
PROGS=sig_demo myar 
OBJECTS=$(PROGS:.c=.o)

all: $(PROGS)

sig_demo.o: sig_demo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c sig_demo.c

sig_demo.c: sig_demo.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c sig_demo.c

myar.o: myar.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myar.c

myar.c: myar.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myar.c

tests:
    testq
    testt
    testv

testq:
    testq24 
    testq135
    testq12345

testq24:
    rm -f ar24.ar 
    ar q ar24.ar 2-s.txt 4-s.txt
    myar q myar24.ar 2-s.txt 4-s.txt 
    diff ar24.ar myar24.ar

testq135:
    rm -f ar135.ar 
    ar q ar135.ar 1-s.txt 3-s.txt 5-s.txt 
    myar q myar135.ar 1-s.txt 3-s.txt 5-s.txt 
    diff ar135.ar myar135.ar

testq12345:
    rm -f ar12345.ar 
    rm -f myar12345.ar
    ar q ar12345.ar 1-s.txt 2-s.txt 3-s.txt 4-s.txt 5-s.txt
    ./myar -q myar12345.ar 1-s.txt 2-s.txt 3-s.txt 4-s.txt 5-s.txt
    diff ar135.ar myar135.ar

testt:
    testt24
    testt135
    testt12345

testt24:
    rm -f ar24.ar
    ar q ar24.ar 2-s.txt 4-s.txt
    ar t ar24.ar > ar-ctoc.txt 
    myar -t ar24.ar > myar-ctoc.txt 
    diff ar-ctoc.txt myar-ctoc.txt 

testt135:
    rm -f ar135.ar
    ar q ar135.ar 1-s.txt 3-s.txt 5-s.txt
    ar t ar135.ar > ar-ctoc.txt 
    myar -t ar135.ar > myar-ctoc.txt 
    diff ar-ctoc.txt myar-ctoc.txt 

testt12345:
    rm -f ar12345.ar
    ar q ar12345.ar 1-s.txt 2-s.txt 3-s.txt 4-s.txt 5-s.txt
    ar t ar12345.ar > ar-ctoc.txt 
    myar -t ar12345.ar > myar-ctoc.txt 
    diff ar-ctoc.txt myar-ctoc.txt  

testv:
    testv24
    testv135
    testv12345

testv24:
    rm -f ar24.ar
    ar q ar24.ar 2-s.txt 4-s.txt
    ar v ar24.ar > ar-ctoc.txt 
    myar -v ar24.ar > myar-ctoc.txt 
    diff ar-ctoc.txt myar-ctoc.txt 

testv135:
    rm -f ar135.ar
    ar q ar135.ar 1-s.txt 3-s.txt 5-s.txt
    ar v ar135.ar > ar-ctoc.txt 
    myar -v ar135.ar > myar-ctoc.txt 
    diff ar-ctoc.txt myar-ctoc.txt 

testv12345:
    rm -f ar12345.ar
    ar q ar12345.ar 1-s.txt 2-s.txt 3-s.txt 4-s.txt 5-s.txt
    ar v ar12345.ar > ar-ctoc.txt 
    myar -v ar12345.ar > myar-ctoc.txt 
    diff ar-ctoc.txt myar-ctoc.txt 




clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) $(OBJECTS) *.o *~
```

Comment: That's a lot of `makefile`. Can you strip it down to a minimal test case?

Comment: Certainly. What it does is compile sig_demo.c and myar.c when make is run. (I apologize, don't understand the code tag syntax for comments)          `gcc -g -Wall -c sig_demo.c` `gcc sig_demo.o -o sig_demo` `gcc -g -Wall -c myar.c` `gcc myar.o -o myar`

Comment: And that all works fine. If I were to run `make tests`: the following occurs: `testq`   `make: testq: command not found` `make: *** [tests] error 127`. If I were to run `make: testq24` I receive: `rm -f ar24.ar`   `ar q ar24.ar 2-s.txt 4-s.txt` `ar: creating ar24.ar` `myar q myar24.ar 2-s.txt 4-s.txt` `make: myar: command not found` `make: *** [testq24] Error 127`

Comment: Because the objective in this makefile is to run tests on the program, which is my implementation of the `ar` command (not really 100% working perfectly to spec). Running `make` is for compiling, `make clean` for removing the droppings, `make tests` for running the commands in various test targets.

Answer (score 2):

[Dependencies](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_dependencies.htm) should be listed on the same line, otherwise it will try to execute them as commands;

For example;

```
tests:
    testq
    testt
    testv
```

will just try to execute the shell commands `testq`, `testt` and `testv` which don't exist and give your error, while;

```
tests: testq testt testv
```

will just see to that the makefile targets `testq`, `testt` and `testv` are completed before the target `tests` is executed. In this case `tests` contains no commands, so the only thing that target does is see to that the depdendencies are executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_dependencies.htm):

A simple makefile consists of "rules" with the following shape:

```
target ... : dependencies ...
        command
        ...
        ...
```

This is what you need to fix:

```
tests: testq testt testv

testq: testq24 testq135 testq12345

testv: testv24 testv135 testv12345
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the second problem is that it can run testq (and therefore testq24) but produces the following error: `make: *** [testq24] Error 127`. If I change `myar ...` to `./myar` ... it gives `make: *** [testq24] Error 255`. I feel that it just doesn't see the local folder, how would I give it a path?

Comment: @Borne2Run_When_SegFault: you can use absolute path, too, or you can reuse the current directory of the Makefile as: `current_dir = $(shell pwd)` or `current_dir = $(notdir $(shell pwd))`.